# MVC 4 WEB API service layer not able to call url from c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, httpresponse, asp.net-web-api

I have an MVC 4 Web api Service layer.
I am trying to call the service layer from my web application with this code

```
HttpResponseMessage responsemsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:51093";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ServiceUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
ListParams LP = new ListParams();
LP.Add("param1", dtDate.SelectedDate);
LP.Add("Param2", AR.GetMaxAccountRefID().ToNonNullString());
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in LP)
            {
                param = param + item.Key + "=" + item.Value + "&";
            }
            try
            {
                responsemsg = client.GetAsync("/api/ProductAccount?" + param, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
            }
if (responsemsg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
          // code
}
```

This is working fine .. and if i am changing the

```
ServiceUrl ="http://192.168.0.139:8080/"; //(Service Hosted path)
```

Then its not calling and getting 404 Error.

Kindly advice me where i am missing anything..

Comment: Are you 100% certain your web server at 192.168.0.139 has the WebAPI code deployed and running on 8080?

Comment: Yes sure. i am able to run the service from the browser directly with this url "http://192.168.0.139:8080/"

Comment: You have a trailing slash on the end of the new Service URL and also a preceding slash at the start of the appending path.